# How create a folder owned by specific username & groupname?

Tags: group, chown, useradd, macos

In mac `groupadd` command does not work:

After `$ sudo mkdir -p /a/b`,

```
a$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  64 12 Jan 09:46 b
a$ pwd
/a
a$
a$
a$ uname -a
 Darwin user01vl 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Sun Dec  1 18:59:03 PST 2019; root:xnu-4903.278.19~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
a$
```

---

1) what is the command to create user name `jenkins` and group name `jenkins` in mac? Don't assume Jenkins installation on Mac node, this scenario is different

2) How to make `/a/b` own by user `jenkins` and part of `jenkins` group?

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, you need to be root (as root user or via `sudo`) to change the ownership of a file or directory. If you are root, it is simply

```
chown jenkins /a/b
chgrp jenkins /a/b
```

EDIT:

I am not a Mac user, but I understood that the command on a Mac would be `dscl`, as in:

```
sudo dscl . create /Groups/jenkins
sudo dscl . create /Groups/jenkins RealName "Jenkins"
sudo dscl . create /Groups/jenkins passwd "*"
sudo dscl . create /Groups/jenkins gid 1234
```

for the group and

```
dscl . -create /Users/jenkins
dscl . -create /Users/jenkins UserShell /bin/bash
dscl . -create /Users/jenkins RealName "Joe Admin" 
dscl . -create /Users/jenkins UniqueID "1234"
dscl . -create /Users/jenkins PrimaryGroupID 1234
dscl . -create /Users/jenkins NFSHomeDirectory /Users/jenkins
```

for the user.

Comment: On the other hand, you could tell the questioner about `dscl` and `install -d`.

Comment: @JdeBP why dscl and these new commands?

Comment: Can't I be a sudoer to run these commands? Because I don't have root password

Comment: Yes, you can `sudo chown`.  To be root in this ontext just means to somehow run those commands with root privileges.

Comment: @OskarSkog but my first question is not answered

Comment: Can you answer my first question?